# Estimating and comparing pre-post treatment effects in multiple pairs of treatment-vs-control groups

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, random-effects-model, manova

I have a dataset from an experiment where the goal was to study in which plant ecotype a treatment with a certain bacteria had the greatest effect. Hence the data consists of a number of control and treatment group pairs, each pair representing a separate ecotype.

There were 10 ecotypes with 8 plants in the treated group and 8 plants in the control group for a total of 160 plants. Measurements included main root length, total root length and number of lateral roots. These measurements were done at the start of the treatment and after a set amount of time.

The research question for this experiment is simply: *How does plant ecotype effect root growth response to treatment with bacteria x*. I would be happy to just to see if one or more of the ecotypes that have a significant treatment effect (e.g. mean difference in main root growth between treated and control group) are significantly differentiated (in the treatment effect itself, not the level of significance) from the other ecotypes with a significant treatment effect. Even more exciting would be to have a complete ranking of the ecotypes with a significant treatment effect.

I am familiar with the comparison of multiple treatment groups against a common control group, but in this case there are a separate control for each treatment group.

A two way ANOVA will tell that it is difference in treatment effect between the ecotypes, but not which of them are statistically different from the others.

It would be fantastic if someone could enlighten me and shed some light over this!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe your data in more detail. How many ecotypes do you have? How many plants (?) were observed in each ecotype? How many measurements were performed on each plant before and after the treatment? Etc.

Comment: Couldn't you simply perform separate t-tests for each treatment-control pair, as long as you adjust your p-values for multiple comparisons (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem)?

Comment: That would surely give the answer to whether there is a statistical difference between the treatment and control for the individual ecotypes but i can not see how this would tell if there is a statistical difference between these differences. In other words: is the difference among the ecotypes in the difference between treatment and control within the ecotypes.

Comment: Thanks for an update with the details (+1). Wow, this is quite an elaborate experimental design! I guess one could write a whole essay if not a book about different ways to analyze it (disclaimer: I am certainly not knowledgeable enough for that). Let me ask two further questions though. First, what *exactly* is your research question? Do you really want to know in which ecotype treatment "had the greatest effect" and that's it? Or do you want to know in which ecotypes treatment had significant effect? Or do you want to compare effects in some particular ecotypes between each other? [CONT.]

Comment: [CONT.] Or maybe in all pairs of ecotypes between each other (that's 45 pairs btw)? Second, how related are the three measures? What are pairwise correlations between them? Any nonlinear relationships (that you could detect e.g. by looking at scatterplots of one measure against another)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! At a first glance I fooled myself to believe this would be a trivial comparison, but just as you pointed out I have come to the realization that there might be a whole bunch of ways to approach this thing. Of the three measurements the total root length is what interest me most. The three measurements are pretty much linearly related within the control groups but in the treated groups things are a bit different, with increased total root length seemingly being a result of increased number and length of lateral roots instead of increased main root length.

Comment: I find your question technically quite interesting, but I am afraid I am really not an expert here and cannot help you much. Edited your question to bump it up and improve visibility, let's see if it attracts some attention. If there are still no replies after some time, I might at least try to provide some pointers.